# Cannot run TensorBoard in Google Cloud JupyterLab instance

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

It seems that after TensorFlow 2.0 released, TensorBoard cannot be opened in Google Cloud JupyterLab.
When I use **Create new TensorBoard** function in JupyterLab, and Enter the path of log files that TensorFlow generated, Path window closes and no response.

TensorBoard can successfully run on the same log file last month.

I tried reinstalling/downgrading components including TensorFlow (from 1.13 to 2.0), TensorBoard, JupyterLab notebook, IPython. There is no change. I tried creating a new JupyterLab instance and running TensorBoard on the default (initial) environment, still no response.

Thanks

Comment: Are the log files froml a 2.0 model? Can you try against a 1.13 model?

Comment: @Lak,Hi Lak,your suggestion is powerful,It's worked when we try tensorflow1.13,thank you so much

Comment: Hi Lak,there is another questions about the tensorboard,can you help me for it?Thank you very much